# Fantasy book where a female character travels through a tree and has become beautiful when she emerges from it

Tags: story-identification, novel

Read a fantasy book about 14 years ago. Don’t remember much, but in the beginning of the book, a woman is being attacked and frightens the assailant by saying the name of someone they fear or predicts will kill them. Can’t remember his name, but he’s a central or main character. In one part of the story, one of the characters travels through a tree and when she comes out, has become beautiful.

Comment: What kind of fantasy? Contemporary? Medieval? Faerie? Powdermages?

Comment: Thanks for replying, medieval I think. It’s one of the few fantasy books I have read so wanted to go back to it but the name escapes me!

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 13):

Sounds like Elizabeth Hayden’s *[Rhapsody](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elizabeth_Haydon#The_Rhapsody_Trilogy)*

The main character, Rhapsody, has magical Naming powers which she uses early on when being attacked by her stalker’s troops.

Later, she and her companions escape by traveling down a world tree through the fire at the centre of the world. Using her Naming to safely pass through she unintentionally remakes herself magically beautiful.