# Book series read in the 2010s about a woman, an assassin, and an orc who must cross lava

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read a book (series really) when I was in high school (8-11 years ago) and I can't remember the title or the author. It was about a woman (I think she was a magician and a whore but not certain), an assassin, and an orc/giant, and they are fleeing and run into a cave and have to cross through the molten lava of the earth. The woman uses some magic and is able to protect them and they come back out to a different land (or time) with their bodies completely made whole. They then find an old castle and proceed to take over the land. I also remember a weaver of time mentioned in the book.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you remember what the covers looked like?  Any names of characters or places?  Did they travel to a different world, or just a different place in their world?

Comment: No names or place names I can remember. I believe it was their world but a different time.

Comment: I remember one about a dog, a goose, and a bag of grain that have to cross a river.  I don't think it was specifically mentioned whether the river was lava or not.

Answer (score 10):

Same as
[Fantasy book where a female character travels through a tree and has become beautiful when she emerges from it](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/267185/fantasy-book-where-a-female-character-travels-through-a-tree-and-has-become-beau): Elizabeth Hayden’s *[Rhapsody](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elizabeth_Haydon#The_Rhapsody_Trilogy)*

[image: Cover of Elizabeth Haydon's "Rhapsody". The cover shows a girl with a bow and arrow in the foreground. Behind her is a Firbolg and a figure cloaked in black holding a weapon. The background is a misty purple with a rocky hill visible. An anecdote says "A stunningly told tale by a new fantasy author who is sure to go far."--Anne Mccaffrey]

Early in the story Rhapsody works as a prostitute. She also has magical powers as a Namer.

Her companions are an assassin and a FirBolg (very large orc-like race), and the three of them flee from a demon into the world tree, climb down its roots to the fire at the centre of the world, and make it through remade due to her singing.

This journey takes ages and when they emerge on the other side of the world it's later enough that their place of origin is a mythical sunken continent where they find a ruined castle which they rebuild and found a new kingdom.

The framing story involves a character in a satellite splicing the reel of time like a movie film to drop a character from the present (post-journey) of most of the story into Rhapsody's past for a few days, bring him back, and then they re-meet in the later time after the journey.

Comment: That cover looks super familiar. Thank you!!!!

Comment: They should have named her Mandy {Rice-Davies} since there is power in Naming {and shaming}

Comment: @ChevalierHafen If you're sure this is right, please click the checkmark on the left of the answer to mark it as correct.